# How do I set a string variable to a string contained in another variable

Tags: java, string

For example, I have a string variable line

```
(line.contains("for") || line.contains("def") || line.contains("if")    || line.contains("while") || line.contains("else") || line.contains("elif")
```

and I want to set a new string variable keyword to the keyword in this conditional statement, how would be able to do this, like keyword = keyword in line.

Comment: @pmcarpan i dont think it is a duplicate, he is asking after the condition he wants to assign to variable that makes true the condition

Comment: `line.contains("if") || line.contains("elif")` is redundant; if the line does not contain `"if"`, then it won't contain `"elif"`.

Comment: @Liamnator why dont you put the keywords in a `List`.

Comment: For the record: if you really try to **parse** some sort of language, then `contains()` is wrong. Then you have to use a parser, to correctly identify and process the different elements of your input. What if the line is `if a == "def"`or something like that?

Answer (score 4):

Stream provide a simple and elegant solution in this case:

```
    String keyword = Stream.of("elif", "for", "def", "if", "while", "else")
            .filter(line::contains)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse("no-keyword-found");
```

Note: "elif" must be placed before "if"

Comment: _"I removed "elif" keyword because it will never be returned."_ → It will, as long as it comes before `if`.

Answer (score 0):

alternative here:

```
List<String> keywords = new LinkedList<String>;
keywords.add("for");  // put your keywords in a list
keywords.add("def");
keywords.add("if");
keywords.add("else");
String strword;
for(keyword:keywords){
 if(line.contains(keyword)){
    String strword = keyword;
 }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this?

```
public static Optional<String> getFirstMatch(String string, String... subStrings)
{
    return Arrays.stream(subStrings).filter(string::contains).findFirst();
}
```

Sample usage:

```
Optional<String> match = getFirstMatch("myInput", "my", "Input");
if (match.isPresent())
{
    String foo = match.get();
    //...
}
```